# Binary Tree Height

Tags: binary-tree

I need a general formula to calculate the minimum height of the binary tree and the maximum height of the binary tree. (not the binary search tree)

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific.

Answer (score 16):

First there may be some difference as to how computer science calculates the 
height of a tree, versus the way height is determined in discrete mathematics 
(graph theory), this may be due to the existence of data at any one node 
(or vertice), while in mathematics, its a pure theory approach.

So maybe its best you clarify which one you need.

In discrete mathematics, trees are classified as m-ary trees, so a 
bin-ary tree is a 2-ary tree. Also at any given height, there can be 
at most 2^h = L (leaves). This is important to notice, since it confirms that
the root is at height zero, hence 2^0 = 1 leaf...1 vertice...the root.

So given n vertices, the height of a tree is given by the formula 
n = 2^( h + 1 ) - 1

Since you are looking for h, you have to take the log2 of both sides of
the formula n = 2^( h + 1 ) - 1

For a full binary tree, the max height is 
log2( n + 1 ) = log2( 2^( h + 1 ) )
this equals ceiling( log2( n + 1 ) - 1 ) = h

For a non-full binary tree, the max height = ( n - 1 )
therefore if you have n vertices, the root must be subtracted to get 
the max height, because of the previous formula above (2^h = L)

For min heights, extrapolate from the above rules.

Answer (score 9):

N - number of nodes.
H - height of the binary tree.

**Complete Binary Tree:**
Then, with H height N would lie between:

```
2^H <= N <= (2^(H+1) - 1)
```

Thus, solving this inequality; we get :

```
H <= lg(N)  and  H >= (lg(N+1) - 1)
```

Hence we finally get:

```
H = floor( lg(N) ) = ceil( (lg(N+1) - 1) )   //as H is integer
```

(lg : log base 2)

**Binary Tree (not necessarily complete):**

```
Max height = N;  

Min Height = floor( lg(N) ) = ceil( (lg(N+1) - 1) )
```

We get minimum height when binary tree is complete.

Answer (score 7):

If you have N elements, the minimum height of a binary tree will be log2(N)+1.

For a full binary tree, the maximum height will be N/2.

For a non-full binary tree, the maximum height will be N.

Comment: How do you know if the tree is full or non full? I am aware that the min height is considered a balanced tree.

Comment: As a full binary tree could only contain an odd number of nodes, the formula of the max tree height would be (N+1)/2.

Answer (score 4):

If a root can have any number of leaves up to 2 (0,1,2) then:

- The max height is **n-1**. This is the case when your tree has only one leaf. No node has more than one branch.
- The min height is **[log2(n)]** where [x] is the integer part of x.

In order to obtain a minimal height every root must have as many branches as possible. In this case you'll notice that for n=1, height=0 ; for n=2 to n=3, height=1; for n=4 to n=7, height=2 ; for n=8 to n=15, height=3 etc.

You can thus notice that, for every n, there exists a p such that:

2^p <= n < 2^(p+1) and p=height, so height = [log2(n)]

Answer (score 2):

Think about how the structure of the tree can change.

For example, if the tree is completely unbalanced then this is the worst case - each node will have exactly one child.  In the best case, the tree is completed balanced, and each node has two children.

Since it sounds like homework, I'll leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

The max height is n and the min height (IE a perfect binary tree) is the (log base 2( n + 1)) - 1

Comment: The min height is from the formula n=2^(h+1)-1 just solve for h.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum height is h=ceiling( log(n+1)/log(2)  -1)
for any binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

Given n nodes:

**min height: floor(log2(n))**
Let's say you have 3 nodes:

```
     root
left/  \right
```

floor(log2(3)) will be floor(1.58) == 1

```
     root
  left/  \right
left2/
```

will be floor(log2(4)) will be floor(2) == 2

**max height: N-1**

root->left1->left2
Here 3 nodes gives a height of 2.

Comment: It's not going to work. Try finding minimum of Full tree with all left tree filled with just one right child.

Comment: I think my answer was for a complete binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

With `n-nodes` the possible maximum height is `floor(log(n))` = `ceil (log(n+1))-1`.

With `n-nodes` the possible minimum height is `n-1`.